# PG_CANCEL_BACKEND doesn't work on Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Sometimes `SELECT PG_CANCEL_BACKEND(id);` doesn't work even when it returns `true`.

I get the process id from the following query.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM pg_stat_activity
WHERE
        pid IN (
        SELECT
            pid
        FROM pg_locks
        WHERE
              granted
          AND relation = 'schema.my_table'::REGCLASS
    );
```

Then I run the `PG_CANCEL_BACKEND`, and I get a `true` (as when the process was cancelled), but when checking the locks, the same process id appears again.

Do you know why this happen and if there is another way to cancel the `pid`?

Answer (score 0):

> I get a `true` (as when the process was cancelled)

No. As described in [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-SIGNAL), `pg_cancel_backend` sends a `SIGINT` to the corresponding process and returns `true` if it was *sent* successfully; there's no guarantee that the signal was handled (blocked, ignored) by the backend.

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60475604/does-linux-kill-return-after-the-process-excute-signal-handler).

Comment: However, if the backend doesn't go away in a short while, that's either a bug in PostgreSQL, or a bug in a PostgreSQL extension, of a disk where I/O requests take forever, or data corruption that sent PostgreSQL into some kind of endless loop.

Comment: Or a long rollback.

Comment: How could there ever be a long rollback in PostgreSQL?

Comment: Since you're obviously much more familiar with Postgres than me, I take your comment to meant that long rollbacks are not something that happens in Postgres. Duly noted.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 0):

You can only cancel a query if the connection is running one.  If it is not running a query (that is, it is 'idle in transaction') then you would need to use pg_terminate_backend() instead.